# Multi-region azure continuous deployment using Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-deployment

This question has two parts:

I have 3 websites hosted in 3 different azure regions. We are using Jenkins for CD. Currently, I am using a `msbuild` from `Jenkins` job and passing a `publishprofile` to it. I have downloaded this `publishprofile` manually from `Azure web app` and kept on a location. But I do not want to do it manually. Is there any automated process exist to download the `publishprofile` during deployment? Ofcourse we can add a `powershell` and do it, but if something is already existing in `Jenkins` pipeline that I can reuse?

Second part of the question, I have same website needs to be deployed in multiple locations, any help how can we achieve this using Jenkins ( no `Container`).